# Refactoring Practice/Workbook

Tags: refactoring

I recently saw the [Refactoring Workbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321109295) while I was cruising Amazon the other day. I haven't actually gotten to read it yet, but it presents an interesting idea. The most enticing part of a "workbook" is that we can finally have every day practice for dealing with tough problems in a systematic way.

Onto the question. Does such a resource exist online or in other books? I know someone is going to suggest Open Source, but some of those projects require understanding of a huge context. I'm looking for something I can pick up, read a few pages, and refactor. Consistently.

As a side note, if such a resource doesn't exist online - it'd be a *gold mine* of an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Industrial Logic has [e-learning resources](https://elearning.industriallogic.com/gh/submit?Action=BrowseAlbumsAction) that I think are somewhat like this.

They aren't free, and I haven't seen enough of them to vouch for the quality, but I know some of the people involved in creating these materials and would expect they're good.